# Evaluating a double integral defined on two intervals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I'm trying to evaluate this double integral, but I can't seem to figure out the limits of integration.

$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}e^{x^2}\:\forall \: y<x
\\ e^{y^2}\: \forall\: y>x \end{matrix}\right.
$$

The double integral of the function is to be evaluated over a domain $D$, where $x>0$ and y<10.

$$\iint_{D}f(x, y)\:dA$$

I understand that x needs to begin at 0, but I can't find where the two parts of the function overlaps. Seems to be at the lines $y \pm x$, but that doesn't really help me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With $\mathrm dA$ you mean $\mathrm d(x,y)$ ?

Comment: Yes, dA as a surface integral over x and y

Comment: The integral can be written as $$\int_0^{10} \,\mathrm dx\left(\int_x^{10}  \exp(y^2)\,\mathrm dy\right)+\int_0^\infty \,\mathrm dx\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\min(x,10)} \exp(x^2)\,\mathrm dy\right)$$ Does that help?

Comment: That's great! But how do I evaluate min(x, 10)?

Comment: You can further decompose the second integral into $\int_0^{10} \,\mathrm dx\dots$ and $\int_{10}^\infty \,\mathrm dx\dots$ But I don't know if you can get a closed form anywayl...